# how to emulate the do while statement in python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pycharm

The problem is the following: Write a program that writes on the screen 1 to 100, 1 in 1, 3 times. The first time should use for and the second while and the third do while,how to emulate the do while statement.
Follow the code as far as I did:

```
i = 0
n = 0
for n in range(100):
 print(n - 1)
 while i < 100:
  print(i)
  i = i + 1
```

Comment: python does not have a do while loop,

Comment: obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't have a do while loop, u can simulate it like this

```
i = 1  

while True:  
    print(i)  
    i = i + 1  
    if(i > 100):  
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method to solve my problem